# Coordinate transform of discrete data

Tags: data, coordinate-transformation

let's say I have a set of discrete data of dimension n by n by n, which may represent a scalar field $f(x,y,z), x,y,z\in [-1/2,1/2]$ in Cartesian 3D space. To be specific,

```
n=64;
data=Table[i+j+k,{i,-n/2,n/2},{j,-n/2,n/2},{k,-n/2,n/2}];
```

so that $f(i/n,j/n,k/n)\simeq data[[i,j,k]]$.
My question is, is there an efficient way to calculate the "spherically integrated" data? i.e., in the continuous form I would like to calculate
$$g(r)=\int f(r\sin\theta\cos\phi,r\sin\theta\sin\phi,r\cos\theta)r^2\sin\theta d\theta d\phi$$
In a less efficient way I would write something like

```
dataSph=Table[0,{l,0,2n}];
For[i=1,i<=n,i++,
  For[j=1,j<=n,j++,
    For[k=1,k<=n,k++,
      For[l=1,l<=2n,l++,
        If[l-1/2<=Sqrt[i^2+j^2+k^2]<l+1/2,dataSph[[l]]+=data[[i,j,k]]]
   ]]]]
```

or even just interpolate the data into a continuous version. Is there any better way to do the job?

Comment: spherical integral can be write such as `Integrate[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2], 
 Element[{x, y, z}, Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, r]]]`

Comment: You state that $(x,y,z) \in [-\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}]^3$ yet then compute `Sqrt[i^2+j^2+k^2]` to determine the "shells". Shouldn't there be an offset involved? E.g. `Sqrt[(i-n/2)^2+(j-n/2)^2+(k-n/2)^2]` or something similar.

Comment: Yes there should be an offset. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Just a quick-n-dirty. This finishes your example on my laptop in about 1/3 of a second vs 10 minutes.

```
idx = Tuples[Range@n, 3];
idxvals = Norm /@ N[idx];
dataSph = ConstantArray[0, 2 n + 1];
For[l = 1, l <= 2 n, l++,
  dataSph[[l]] = 
    Total[Extract[data, 
      Pick[idx, Unitize[Clip[idxvals, l + {-1/2, 1/2}, {0, 0}]], 1]]];
  ];
```